# How to properly package a Nuget distributed custom tool that generates source code as part of the build

Tags: c#, .net-core, msbuild, nuget, build-tools

Thanks to [this](https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/11/11/build-tools-in-nuget/) awesome article by Nate McMaster, I know how to package a .NET core console application as a Nuget package that automatically installs itself as a (pre, in this instance) build task.

To test if everything works, I simply had my custom tool write out a public C# class.

**[Here is the complete and runnable sample on Github](https://github.com/aniongithub/CustomTool)**.

However, the file that my custom tool adds isn't really part of the build (the first one that actually generates the file) and therefore the introduced class is not in the assembly after the first build (see Line 38  [here](https://pastebin.com/531fzb1L)). However, because the .NET core projects now automatically include all .cs files alongside the project, it builds the new class into the output on subsequent builds (see Line 57 [here](https://pastebin.com/531fzb1L)).

The generated files don't go away on clean, though and generally don't behave like something an MSBuild task would output. However, because the exec happens in a targets file, we ought to have access to all the machinery to make this happen. So my question is:

How do I correctly execute a custom build tool (console app) that needs to examine the project, its files and generate source code (preferably in obj/ as say `<foo>.g.cs` that gets compiled into the resulting assembly as part of a single build? Ideally, this generated file(s) shouldn't appear in the solution explorer, either.

Help!

Comment: Add a build targets that gets called before actual build. Example taken from Refit library: https://github.com/reactiveui/refit/blob/master/Refit/targets/refit.targets .

Comment: I don't understand. This is what I do here (https://github.com/aniongithub/CustomTool/blob/master/CustomTool/RunCustomTool.targets#L12). Also, the example you linked to uses `UsingTask` which is an MSBuild task with its own set of troubles, see here: https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/11/11/msbuild-task-with-dependencies/

I'd like to do this using a console app + MSBuild glue containing an Exec call.

Comment: You would need to include the generated intermediate file as compile item (see line 44 https://github.com/reactiveui/refit/blob/5b4e14aaf8a1fcc27396b7c08171d100aba1b97d/Refit/targets/refit.targets#L44 ).

Comment: Note to resolve the intermediate path (see line 11 https://github.com/reactiveui/refit/blob/5b4e14aaf8a1fcc27396b7c08171d100aba1b97d/Refit/targets/refit.targets#L11 ).

Comment: Awesome, updated my sample and will probably make this into a custom dotnet template as well! Could you please post this as an answer so I can accept? Thanks again! :)

Comment: Glad I could help. I added it as answer ;-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When generating the intermediate file (CustomTool.g.cs) in the intermediate folder (you'll need to resolve it, see example in Refit library: https://github.com/reactiveui/refit/blob/5b4e14aaf8a1fcc27396b7c08171d100aba1b97d/Refit/targets/refit.targets#L11); you need to explicitly add it as a compile item.

Taking your example targets file (https://github.com/aniongithub/CustomTool/blob/master/CustomTool/RunCustomTool.targets#L13):

```xml
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IntermediateOutputPath Condition="$(IntermediateOutputPath) == '' Or $(IntermediateOutputPath) == '*Undefined*'">$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)obj\$(Configuration)\</IntermediateOutputPath>

    <!-- Command to invoke CustomTool -->
    <CustomTool>dotnet "$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)/netcoreapp2.2/CustomTool.dll"</CustomTool>

    <!-- Other variables  -->
    <CustomVariable>"$(MSBuildProjectDir)"</CustomVariable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="CustomTool" BeforeTargets="CoreCompile" DependsOnTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <Exec Command="$(CustomTool) $(ProjectPath) $(IntermediateOutputPath)CustomTool.g.cs" />

    <!-- add generated file as a compile item, otherwise it won't get picked up -->
    <ItemGroup Condition="Exists('$(IntermediateOutputPath)\CustomTool.g.cs')">
      <Compile Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)\CustomTool.g.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: Please use the Github link in my question to see the full source of the final solution. Thanks @Styxxy !